# arcgis silverlight - how to delete/cut a part of a multipart polygon

Tags: arcgis-silverlight-api

Say I cloned a single-part lake polygon that had a hole for an island. Then I used the Editor [Reshape](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//01m800000003000000) command to cut a piece off. That incidentally caused a second part to be created where the island was, as seen here.

[image]

Now I want to get rid of that bogus island.

I've tried drawing a circle around it with the [Cut](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Splitting_a_polygon/01m800000024000000/) command, tried the Reshape command again, no joy.

Help a dummy out?

(yeah I know my links are to ArcGIS Desktop editing tools, the better descriptions of the apparently more or less equivalent Silverlight API Editor commands)  ;-)

Comment: if your silverlight options are equivalent to desktop, can you edit blue feature, create a square or circle to cover island, then select both the blue feature and your new shape and via editor toolbar merge the two (this is a quick/dirty way via desktop - perhaps it will work for you)?